# PHP/XML routing working for one route, not for the other

Tags: php, regex, xml, oop, routes

Currently trying to code a simple bloging cms in OOP-PHP, I've encountered a little snag.
To get users to the propre page, I've made a simple router, checking requested uri versus xml routing file by means of a simple preg_match. here are the codes:

in my bootstrap file:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$router = new Router($manager, $uri);
$content = $router->route();
```

In my router file:

```
public function route()
{
    $uri = $this->uri;

    foreach ($this->routes as $route) {
        if (preg_match('#^'.$route->getUri().'$#', $uri, $matches)) {
            if (!empty($route->getParams())) {
                $route->setVars($matches[1]);
            }
            $controllerClass = '\Controller\\'.$route->getController();
            $controller  = new $controllerClass($this->manager);
            $action = $route->getAction().'Action';

            if (!empty($route->getVars())) {
                $content = $controller->$action($route->getVars());
            } else {
                $content = $controller->$action();
            }

            return $content;
        } else {
            return $content = header('Location: View/404.php');
        }
    }

}
```

In my routing xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<routes>
    <route uri="/([0-9]*)" params="page" controller="BlogController" action="index" />
    <route uri="/post-([0-9]+)" params="id" controller="BlogController" action="view" />
</routes>
```

The problem: routing works just fine for the index action, even though I have a pagination system, but not for single post viewing.
Preg_Match seems to catch perfectly fine the index route and if parenthesis, redirecting to the proper page, but when I try to see a single post, I get redirected on my 404 error page.

For reference, the Index template file, so you can see the links are correct:

```
 public function display($page)
{
    $display = '<h1>Liste des articles présentés sur ce blog:</h1><br />';
    $posts = $this->posts;
    $pages = $this->pages;

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if (strlen($post->getContent()) > 200) {
            $debut = substr($post->getContent(), 0, 200);
            $debut = substr($debut, 0, strrpos($debut, ' ')).'...';
            $post->setContent($debut);
        }
        if ($post->getNbComment() == 0 || $post->getNbComment() == null) {
            $comments = 'Aucun commentaire. ';
        } else if ($post->getNbComment() == 1) {
            $comments = 'Un commentaire. ';
        } else {
            $comments  = $post->getNbComment().' commentaires. ';
        }

        $display .=
        '<div class="row">
            <h3 class="col-sm-8"><a href="/post-'.$post->getId().'">'.htmlspecialchars($post->getTitle()).'</a></h3>
            <div class="col-sm-12">'.nl2br(htmlspecialchars($post->getContent())).'</div>
            <p class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-4"><em>Par '.htmlspecialchars($post->getAuthor()).' le '.$post->getDate()->format('d-m-Y').'.</em> '.$comments.'</p>
        </div>';
    }

    $display .= '<div class="btn-group" role="button">';
    for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        $display .= '<a href="/'.$i.'" ';
        if ($i == $page) {
            $display .= 'class="btn btn-primary">'.$i.'</a>';
        } else {
            $display .= 'class="btn btn-default">'.$i.'</a>';
        }
    }
    $display .= '</div>';

    return $display;
}
```

I'm currently lost, and even my rubber duck cannot help me on this one. And needless to say that I checked if the same question had not been asked and couldn't find one.

Thank you for your time, and please excuse my english if I made any mistake.

**EDIT:**

As asked in first answer, here is the var_dump of `$this->routes` in the router file. As you can see, both routes are correctly defined in the router file and in the xml file.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Lib\Route)[13]
      private 'uri' => string '/([0-9]*)' (length=9)
      private 'params' => string 'page' (length=4)
      private 'controller' => string 'BlogController' (length=14)
      private 'action' => string 'index' (length=5)
      private 'vars' => null
  1 => 
    object(Lib\Route)[11]
      private 'uri' => string '/post-([0-9]+)' (length=14)
      private 'params' => string 'id' (length=2)
      private 'controller' => string 'BlogController' (length=14)
      private 'action' => string 'view' (length=4)
      private 'vars' => null
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem you have here is the exit condition in your loop in your `route()` function. You're looping over all your routes, but in fact, you're returning from that function right after evaluating only the first route.

You need to get rid of your `else` case and only redirect to the 404 page when no routes are found.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: What do you have now ?

Comment: Same thing, instantly redirected to the 404 error page, as if preg_match doesn't catch the post-([x]) pattern.

Comment: Did you try escaping the `/` and '-' characters?

Comment: First thing I tried yes. But to no effect. Plus they aren't metacharacters anyway, I triple checked

Comment: Good idea! It's done. As you can see, both routes are defined and present in the router. The preg_match just doesn't want to take the second one in account it seems.

Comment: Well, the last thing I can think of would be to know how your post IDs look like. Your preg_match function and regex look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. 404 redirection condition was still misplaced but the bug was present nontheless. Definitely resolved by changed the links to single posts from `/post-[x]`to `/view/[x]`

Has anyone ever had such problem with `preg_match()`?